# Template member function (on type T) of non-template class T

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to do something like:

```
class A {
  public:
    void f();
  private:
    void g() { };
};

class B {
  public:
    void f();
  private:
    void g() { };
};

template<typename T>
void T::f() {
    g();
}

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    a.f();
    b.f();
}
```

however T::f() does not compile.

Possible workarounds could be making f() non-member:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T* t);
```

Or using CRTP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

But is there no C++ syntax to do as above?

EDIT: I have a big function f() whose code is shared by the 2 classes A and B. A and B have the same interface, which f() uses. However, because we are not using runtime polimorphism (i.e, virtual functions), the corpus of f() needs to be instantiated twice at compile time, once for A and once for B. Templates are made exactly for this purpose. The function f(), in my case, should be template function whose template type is the type of *this.

Comment: The above (wiki) is a perfect valid c++ syntax. But I see what you ask and I say no, no shorthand for doing the above. At least in c++03 world, as I know it.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you can't shrink multiple definitions into one single "template" definition. You can achieve similar effect using preprocessor though.

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Without made-up syntax, just an explanation.

Comment: Templates are instantiated for a given type, you can't just say "this is `T::f` for every `T` in `{every_type}`".

Comment: How about sticking `f()` in a separate base class?

Comment: I added an explanation.
f() can be added in a common base class, but in order to be call A.g() or B.g() I need to make g() virtual or use CRTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using a free function and retaining the `instance.f()` syntax. The function needs to be marked as a friend in order to access the private methods:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace details
{
    template<class T>
    static void f_impl(T* _this)
    {
        _this->g();
    }
}

class A {
public:
    template<class T> friend void details::f_impl(T*);
    void f()
    {
        details::f_impl(this);
    }
private:
    void g()
    {
        std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B {
public:
    template<class T> friend void details::f_impl(T*);
    void f()
    {
        details::f_impl(this);
    }
private:
    void g()
    {
        std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    a.f();
    b.f();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Free function is the correct answer. You should prefer free functions over member functions anyway, for this exact reason: you extend the interface without intruding on the class.

In this case, a free function with an unconstrained template is a bit ugly, because you only need it to work for two cases, not all cases. You should do something like this:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T>
    void f(T* t)
    {
        // implement stuff
    }
}

void f(A* x)
{
    detail::f(x);
}

void f(B* x)
{
    detail::f(x);
}
```

Now you can restrict access to that function via overloading.